# Waiting for process does not work when wShowWindow is set to hide

Tags: c++, windows, process, createprocess

So I am trying to launch new process and wait for it to complete.

```
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

BOOL bCreate = 
    CreateProcess( NULL, const_cast<LPTSTR>( cLine.c_str() ), 
                   NULL, NULL,FALSE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi );
```

Now I just wait for it like this

```
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, wTime_ms)
```

Now if I do not use SW_HIDE this works great. Once I hide the window wait does not return.
What am I doing wrong and how can I wait for hidden process?

thanks

Comment: I imagine that you have a fair amount of trouble to get to a program that doesn't have any window to activate.  All you can do is terminate it with Task Manager.  Or not use SW_HIDE, not much point in creating zombies.  A well designed program will ignore it, that's not exactly common.

Comment: i am not creating zombie. the process completes successfully my wait does not... and the reason for this is that I do not want to pop up another cmd it needs to be background

Comment: If the process exits, the wait will be satisfied.  Whether the process is hidden or not is irrelevant.  Either the process isn't really exiting, or there's a bug in your code.  Also: I don't think the combination of SW_HIDE and CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE makes sense; is this a GUI program or a console program?  Finally, the cast to `LPTSTR` in the call to `CreateProcess` isn't safe.  Copy the command line to a TCHAR buffer and pass that to `CreateProcess`.